# "invalid symbol name" after Android Studio crashed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I was editing a layout in Android Studio and added a Switch. 
I first set its ID to "switch". After a compilation error, I realized it was a reserved keyword and I cannot use it, so I decided to change its ID to "mySwitch" but Android Studio crashed at this moment.

After launching it again, I checked the ID, which does have been changed to "mySwitch", but when trying to compile, I still get this error:

```
/path/to/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/example/program/R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.program:id/switch'.
```

I guess Android Studio did not change all occurences of "switch" before crashing, but I did not find any.

What I tried but did not work :

- Changing again the ID
- Deleting and adding again the Switch
- Clean Project

Is there any occurence of my Switch ID I did not think of ?

Comment: try to remove the build folder from the file explorer by yourself without clean/build .. then try to clean again .. it should work

Comment: @ahmedewess it did not work, and I actually get this error in the cleaning process

Comment: dont use AndroidStudio/clean -> navigate to the folder in your hard disk then shift + delete the build folder

Comment: Yes, I deleted the folder, then used Clean after that

Comment: Have you tried the "Invalidate Caches/Restart" option (under the File menu)?

Comment: I just tried that, still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, I should have thought of that earlier.
What I did is `right click on "my_layout.xml"` > `Analyze` > `Inspect Code...`

Then it showed me this line

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/switch"
```

I don't know how I missed that...

Comment: I already told you "I still doubt, if you have missed to change id with name switch somewhere else. Think that way also.." this in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

you need to find where in your xml code an object had taken "null" as an id `android:id="@+id/null"`

so first you need to go to the last xml you edited 
1  - click right on it 
2  - Analyse 
3  - Inspect Code ...
4  - click ok and you will see how much errors and warnings you have

Answer (score 0):

try manually deleting the build folder in your project and use "build" -> "Rebuild Project". By that way all mapping files (including your inconsistent layout mapping) should also go away. and Rebuilding recreates the map.

I still doubt, if you have missed to change id with name switch somewhere else. Think that way also..

Comment: Now I get another error `'boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp' file not found` (I have some functions written in native C++), which is weird because I didn't have that before

Comment: And when I try to `Make Project` after that, I get the first error again

Comment: I am sorry to hear that... Can you please check your proxy settings to your android studio in settings... i think if you have an error with c libraries something might have interrupted the library download...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already found the solution, see my answer (and it was actually pretty stupid... well, I guess it happens ?)

Answer (score 0):

same xlm file you declear samething like

```
`android:id="@+id/null`enter code here`
```

find it and fix;
from right click on eath xml file..and run   analyze--->Inspect Code

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your last edited xml file if it shows the error of invalid name symbol where id is assigned to null go through the code and check all the id's in my case the layout constraints were assigned null value. Check the id's and either remove them or assign them suitable values

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have not named your resource a system reserved name like Continue.xml or such.