# Android resource linking failed: id/null

Tags: android

[Here's the image for my Activity][1]

Android resource linking failed
D:\Androidu2\Final-Project-ITE010\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\example\clearn\R.java: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.clearn:id/null'.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with no more information. Post code or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294556/invalid-symbol-name-after-android-studio-crashed     I guess it might be useful to you.